# how to print total post count with 2 custom fields (date-range)

Tags: php

I have 2 custom fields associated with each post in Y-m-d format: start_date being the start date of the post and end_date being the ending date.

I can easily display upcoming post, current post and past post, but I cannot get the meta_query right to display total post count of upcoming post or current post or past post (with a start date less than or equal to today AND end date greater than or equal to today). The code below displays upcoming post :

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 hours'));
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'paged' => $paged,
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query'=>array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

with this code i am able to display current post with date range but i want to print total post count.

please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the return of `query_post(...)` as a variable, and then run `$var->found_posts`, does that give you the expected result?

Like so:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 hours'));
$query = query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'paged' => $paged,
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query'=>array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
));
echo $query->found_posts . " posts.";
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

If you adjust the compare-value in the query you should get the according result?!

Comment: Vincens von Bibra thank you for replying. i tried this but i am getting no total count value.

please help ?

Comment: What do you get? What does the line `echo $query->found_posts . " posts.";` print out?

Comment: its only print "posts."

Comment: And `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` also prints nothing?

Comment: getting all post title from date range, but i am not getting total post count. can you please code from your end and try to see output ?

Comment: Oh, I see where your mistake is. You have to change `$query = query_posts(array(` to `$query = new WP_Query(array(`. After I changed that it printed "14 posts." for example.

Comment: hey Vincens von Bibra! first of all sorry for late reply, i was bizy with some other things, today i have checked the code and its working. thanks for your support. its working fine. i have one other query which i have post today. link : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303257/how-to-display-active-upcoming-and-past-event-with-featured-listing-with-pagina

can you please help me to solve this ? thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I will have a look at the other question.

Comment: yes, you save my time. thanks again and waiting for your next support on other question.

Comment: Vincens von Bibra, did you check?