# how to display active, upcoming and past event with featured listing with pagination

Tags: php, wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

I have a code that work fine for **Active Events** Page, **Upcoming Event** Page & **Past Event** Page with a event_start_date later than today.

**What I want is?**

**A :** To show **Active, Upcoming, Past** event post list with **pagination** on there page between dates, ***For example :***

1. If today is 11 May 2018, and an event with the dates 9 to 25 May then this listing show on **Active Event page**.
2. If today is 11 May 2018, and an event with the dates 20 to 30 May or June/July then this listing show on **Upcoming Event page**,
3. If today is 11 May 2018, and an event with the dates 5 to 8 March or April/May then this listing show on **Past Event page**.

**B :** I also want **Featured listing** too, 
***For example :***

if i have 10 or 20 events posts on **Active event page** and i want to make **5th**/**8th**/**15th** no post to be **featured listing**, then if i right tick to my Featured Listing (meta_key: event_featured, meta_value : yes) then those post (**5/8/15**) display list on top, and after that other post ie: **1,2,3,4,6,7,9 - - - -** will display.

**C:** i also want to display those **5/8/15** no post in **different color** with other post.

**D:** i also want to display those **5/8/15** post **order by** date. ***For example :***

if **5th** no. event post start date = 6 May , **8th** no. event post start date = 11 May, and **15th** no event start date = 9 May then Event listing display will be : **5**th/**15**th/**8**th  after that other event post list display **order by** date.

now final active event list will be like : **5/15/8/1/2/3/6/7/4/9/10 - - - - -**

**E :** i also want this type of **pagination**, ***For example :***

if i have **20 active event post** listing and **5/8/15** no. post is **featured listed** and i want to show **6 post per page** then i want **pagination** like this :

**1 page listing :**  5/8/15/1/2/3

**2 page listing :**  4/6/7/9/10/11

**3 page listing :**  12/13/14/16/17/18

over all i don't want to repeat featured listing on pagination.

**Problem :** I don't want to use **sticky option**, because if i active sticky on any **active event** post then it is showing to **upcoming** and **past event** listing too and its also appear on pagination next pages too.

***here is my simple code but its not fulfill my requirements :***

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 hours'));
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post', 
 'posts_per_page' => 1,  
 'paged' => $paged,
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query'=>array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
);
```

can any one help me to make perfect code for my page requirements?

thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English..

Comment: still waiting for solution :(

Comment: any one can help me plz?